# Postgresql combine multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have following sql:

```
with modules as (
    select *
    from translate_dev.tab_module as m
             join translate_dev.tab_translation_module as tm on m.id = tm.module_id
)
select tm.name,
       t.id,
       t.language_id,
       t.text
from translate_dev.tab_translation as t
         join modules as tm on tm.translation_id = t.id
        
where t.id in (
               1166615, 1166401, 1166578, 1166579, 1166580, 1166581, 1166582, 1166583, 1166584, 1166586, 1166587,
               1166588, 1166589, 1166591, 1166595, 1166597, 1166598, 1166599, 1166600, 1166601, 1166602, 1166603,
               1166604, 1166605, 1166606, 1166607, 1166608, 1166610, 1166612, 1166614, 1166616, 1166617, 1166618,
               1166619, 1166621, 1166623, 1166624, 1166626, 1166627, 1166628, 1166629, 1166631, 1166632, 1166633,
               1166634, 1166635, 1166636, 1166637, 1166638, 1166640, 1166641, 1166642, 1166643, 1166644, 1166645,
               1166646, 1166650, 1166651, 1166652, 1166653, 1166654, 1166655, 1166656, 1166657, 1166658, 1166659,
               1166662, 1166664, 1166665, 1166667, 1166668, 1166669, 1166671, 1166672, 1166673, 1166674, 1166675,
               1166676, 1166677, 1166678, 1166679, 1166680, 1166681, 1166682, 1166683, 1166685, 1166688, 1166689,
               1166693, 1166696, 1166697, 1166698, 1166699, 1166700, 1166701, 1166702, 1166704, 1166705, 1166706,
               1166707, 1166709, 1166710, 1166712, 1166713, 1166714, 1166716, 1166717, 1166718, 1166719, 1166721,
               1166722, 1166723, 1166725, 1166726, 1166727, 1166728, 1166730, 1166731, 1166733, 1166734, 1166735,
               1166736, 1166741, 1166742, 1166743, 1166744, 1166745, 1166747, 1166748, 1166749, 1166751, 1166752,
               1166753, 1166754, 1166755, 1166756, 1166757, 1166758, 1166759, 1166760, 1167155, 1167157, 1167158,
               1167539, 1167540, 1167546, 1167966, 1167967, 1168007, 1168010, 1168011, 1168012, 1168014, 1168015,
               1168016, 1168017, 1168018, 1168019, 1168020, 1168021, 1168022, 1168023, 1168024, 1168025, 1168026,
               1168027, 1168028, 1168029, 1168030, 1168031, 1168032, 1168033, 1168034, 1168035
    )
order by t.id, t.language_id
```

Which results in (only an example):
[image]

What i want though is **one** result row for the `id` in which the `text` of the specific `language_id` is appended as extra column.

What i mean is:

| Name | id | bg | cs | de | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MobileServices | 1166401` | bg translated text | cs translated text | de translated text | ... |

Someone has an idea how to do this? I tried it the `crosstab` function but since the sql needs to be a string in the function i have problems figuring out the error stacktraces.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You should try to write a [mcve]. The code in your question is not minimal.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Postgres provides `filter` for this purpose:

```
select tm.name, t.id,
       max(t.text) filter (where t.language_id = 'bg') as bg,
       max(t.text) filter (where t.language_id = 'cs') as cs,
       . . .
from translate_dev.tab_translation t join
     modules tm
     on tm.translation_id = t.id
        
where t.id in (. . . )
group by tm.name, t.id
```